# C++ code to parse an XML file and extract data from it

Tags: visual-c++-2010

I want to write a C++ code to parse an XML file and extract data from it.

However, I'm an absolute beginner so I just searched Google. 
Most people seem to refer an "Xerces" library to do this job, so i went ahead with it.

However, the online documentation of the Xerces library is a little lean on examples and sample programs. 
I found an article in Code project on "Writing an XML file using the Xerces library", but none to read from an XML file and extract data from it.

If someone can give me a small sample code to read and extract data from an XML file (using the Xerces library), or if they can direct me to a site/article that gives a small tutorial on the same, I would be really grateful.